# highlight search word in webview android 4.0.4

Tags: android, webview

I have a lot of search in google but still i didn't get the solutions for that questions .the below code is working for the android2.3 and 4.3.but that code not work in android 4.0.4

```
 webview.findNext(true);
 int i=webview.findAll(strr); 
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found "+i+" results !",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 try{  
  Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);  
  m.invoke(webview, true); 
  Log.e("click func clicked:","func clicked:");
  }catch(Exception ignored){}
```

So,anyone give me suggestion about my problem..

Advance in thanks....

Comment: And what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this highlighting the search text method for the android 4.0.4

```
String strr=search_text.getText().toString();

WebView web=(WebView)findviewbyid(R.id.webview);
web.findAll(strr);
try {
    for (Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp")) {
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke((web), true);
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```